# how to use regex to acquire every field in a list-like string in java?

Tags: java, regex, regex-group

I wanna parse a string like `{"aaa","bbb", "ccc"}` to `aaa,bbb,ccc`. How can I do it in regex in java? I've tried to write code as below:

```
String s = "{\"aaa\",\"bbb\", \"ccc\"}";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\{\\\"([\\w]*)\\\"([\\s]*,[\\s]*\\\"([\\w]*)\\\")*}");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
if(matcher.find())      {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    int cnt = matcher.groupCount();
    for(int i = 0; i < cnt; ++i)        {
        System.out.println(matcher.group(i));
    }
}
```

but the output is

```
{"aaa","bbb", "ccc"}
aaa
, "ccc"
```

I have a feeling that this is something about group and no-greedy match, but I don't know how to write it, could anyone help me? Thanks a lot!

**P.S.** I know how to do it with method like `String.replace`, I just wanna know could it be done by regex. Thanks

**Thanks for all your answers and time, but what I want at first is a delegate solution using regex in java, especially group in `regex`. I want to know how to use `group` to solve it.**

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use `s = s.replace("\"", "")` and then chop off the beginning and ending braces using `s = s.substring(1, s.length() - 1)` instead of a regex?

Comment: @merlin2011 then split by regex: `, ?`

Comment: @Judking, can you tell us a little more? 
Do your strings have escaped quotes or commas that we may not want to remove?

Comment: @ka, Yes, I misunderstood the question at first, but yes.

Comment: @Pragnani: this is not JSON.

Comment: @merlin2011 I know how to do it without using regex, could it be done using regex??Thx

Comment: @JBNizet Haven't see that clearly, thanks to let know my wrong..

Comment: @Judking You can try my answer as alternative.. without using replace() method as your wish

Comment: @Pragnani Thanks guy, what I want at first is a delegate solution using regex in java, especially group in `regex`. I want to know how to use `group` to solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RegEx ONLY matching: *quite complex*

RegEx Pattern: `(?:\{(?=(?:"[^"]+"(?:, ?|(?=\})))*\})|(?!^)\G, ?)"([^"]+)"`
Note: it needs the **global** modifier **g**, *needs escaping*, works with **unlimited** number of tokens

Explained demo here: http://regex101.com/r/iE9gS1

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
import java.util.*;
public class Main{

    public static void main(String[] args){
        String s = "{\"aaa\",\"bbb\", \"ccc\"}";
        s = s.substring(1,s.length() -1 );
        s = s.replace("\"","");
        String[] sa = s.split(", ?");
        for (int i = 0; i < sa.length; i++)
            System.out.println(sa[i]);
    }   
}
```

Comment: I know how to do it without using regex, could it be done using regex??Thx

Comment: better `split("(?<=\"), ?(?=\")")` first then replace the quotes! in case there are comma separated values inside the `"quotes"`

Answer (score 1):

Try this sample code :

```
public class RegexTester {
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String data = "{\"aaa\",\"bbb\", \"ccc\"}";

    String modifiedData = data.replaceAll("\\{|\"|\\}", "");

    System.out.println("Modified data : " + modifiedData);
}
```

Using regex try this pattarn :

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\{\"(.+?)\"(,?)\"(.+?)\"(,?)\\s*\"(.+?)\"");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(data);
    System.out.println("Started");
    while (matcher.find()) {

        System.out.print(matcher.group(1));
        System.out.print(matcher.group(2));
        System.out.print(matcher.group(3));
        System.out.print(matcher.group(4));
        System.out.print(matcher.group(5));
    }
```

Hope this addresses your issue.

Comment: I know how to do it without using regex, could it be done using regex??Thx

Comment: @Judking: ReplaceAll uses a regex as its search term, so this is using regular expressions

Comment: I have modified my answer and provided a sample regex pattern.